Is there an Office script to paste an image (png) of a specified range to an email body?
As a stopgap until systems get improved, I have a "form" some business partners use to submit a request for services from my group.  It is not a "Form" in the technical sense, but a formatted excel worksheet (all cells locked except for the input fields).
I have an office script assigned to a button to "clear entries" but I'd like to add another button which exports the completed form as an image (base64 png will suffice) to an email.  It would be even better if the email could be pre-populated with a certain email address.
This "form" is only an internal document, so the cloud-based Outlook 365 will be the default email client used (Just about all users only use the cloud version, and not the app version).
I really hope one of you all-stars can help me out!  Thanks in advance! :)
(Please bear with me, I'm not an expert but do love to learn!)
I have come across an older post with VBA language, but I think some of the commands have changed for office 365 (?)
Here is what I've found; (I'm using a named range called "form" which is $A$1:$I$27  Also, there are portions of the following script which have not yet been customized to my desired use):
(the system is telling me I need to use CTRL+K/indent by 4 before I can post this. Despite everything I try, this doesn't work, hence the block quote formatting - sorry about that)
 Option Explicit
 
 Sub Create_Email(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String)
 
 
 Dim form As Range
 Dim outlookApp As Object
 Dim Outmail As Object
 Dim strTempFilePath As String
 Dim strTempFileName As String
 
 'Name it anything, doesn't matter
 strTempFileName = "EmailForm"
 
 'form is defined as NAMED RANGE in the workbook, do modify this name before use
 Set form = Range("form")
 Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Outmail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
 'Create an email
 With Outmail
   .To = strTo
     .Subject = strSubject
 
 'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
 Call createPNG(form, strTempFileName)
 
 'Embed the image in Outlook
 strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
   .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0
 
 'Change the HTML below to add Header (Dear John) or signature (Kind Regards) using newline tag (<br />)
   .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.png' style='border:0'>"
 
 
     .Display
 
 End With
 
 Set Outmail = Nothing
 Set outlookApp = Nothing
 Set form = Nothing
 
 End Sub
 
 Sub createPNG(ByRef Request_Form As Range, nameFile As String)
 
 Dim wksName As String
 
 wksName = form.Parent.Name
 
 'Delete the existing PNG file of same name, if exists
 On Error Resume Next
 Kill Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png"
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 'Copy the range as picture
 form.CopyPicture
 
 'Paste the picture in Chart area of same dimensions
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Add(form.Left, form.Top, form.Width, form.Height)
   .Activate
   .Chart.Paste
 'Export the chart as PNG File to Temp folder
   .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
 End With
 Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
 
 End Sub
 


Are looking for OfficeScripts or VBA solution? They are different coding language.

Office script, please

While it's possible to use Office Scripts and Power Automate to email the image of a range, there unfortunately isn't a straightforward way to trigger that with a button in an Excel workbook. However, the following tutorials may be able to offer a workaround:

Trigger a flow from a button: https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-automate-from-excel/
Email the image of a range: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/email-images-chart-table

Specifically:

Follow the steps in the first tutorial to create an HTTP-triggered flow.
Create an additional Office Script with the following code (you can customize this as needed, this is just the basic code to get an image of a range):

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, name: string): string {
    return workbook.getNamedItem(name).getRange().getImage();
}


Insert a "run script" action before the "send email" action to run this new script, and specify the name of the range
Modify the body of the "send email" action to include the image. You'll need to switch to code view and add the following, plus any additional message you want (the second tutorial demonstrates this):

<img src="data:image/png;base64,@{outputs('Run_script')?['body/result']}"/>

Sorry that there isn't a more straightforward solution, but hopefully this works for you! Let me know if you have any further questions.

I was able to build what I was looking for (a button within the excel sheet which would email an image of a named range using this video for instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeCqaokSSoQ&t=201s  However, it seems using the HTTP-driven automate step requires premium access.  :/

I was able to get premium access and using the instructions in that video linked above, everything is working exactly like I'd hoped...albeit a little slow. :)
